# Meaning difference when a word can be both a Noun and an Adjective

Tags: word-usage, differences

Does the meaning of "unknown" change depending on whether it is used as a noun or an adjective?

> 1. The cause is still unknown.
> 2. The cause is still an unknown.

Although "unknown" is used as an example, I want to know in general how will people choose the noun form or adjective form

More example:

1. You are pretty
2. You are a pretty

Comment: To me, using ***an*** *unknown* connotes a thought process at a slightly higher level of abstraction- i.e., you are categorizing the "knowns", and the "unknowns" in a particular problem (there may be other categories as well- e.g., "assumptions") and you are saying that one of this problem's attributes, its cause, belongs to the set of "unknowns".  On the other hand saying, "The cause is still unknown" is simply stating that nobody knows what caused it.

Comment: By the way, "pretty" is NOT used as a noun. _You are a pretty."_ is incorrect usage.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I can't agree to you. See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pretty

Comment: @Jim I would love to see your comment to be in the answer section because you are the only one that attempted to response to my question, although those are just your personal feeling.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock you commented below, wrong spot. And I dont know whats wrong with your browser, the site I quoted does have pretty as noun (see number 9.), try again next time.

Comment: Ah, I see it now; right you are. Come to think of it, I should have remembered it from The Wizard of Oz, wherein the Wicked Witch calls Dorothy "my pretty".  Of course, I've not heard it used as a noun before or since, so I assumed that usage was outmoded. That's what I should have said, rather than incorrect.  As for "how do they sound to the listener", well... pretty odd, and pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Both refer to things that are not known.

> [unknown](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unknown) (adj.) - not known; not well-known; not famous
>   [unknown](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unknown) (n) - a place, situation, or thing that you do not know about or understand; a person who is not famous or well-known; something that is not known or not yet discovered

Comment: Thanks. Sure I know they both mean the same, but I am asking in the way how you use them (noun or adj.) do they differ in meaning or how do they sound to the listener.